# Broken fgets input when underflow in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, input, fgets

I'm trying to make a string reverse program. I'm trying to fix bugs with over/underflow. I fixed the first one, so now I've set MAX = 8 just to make it easier to debug.
It works correctly. But when my input is shorter than MAX, the program breaks down.

[image]

So, as you can see, the string "QWERTY ASDFGH" is cut correctly and I have "QWERTY A" (which is exactly 8 characters), then the program reverses it and the output is "A YTREWQ". It does exactly what I want.

But if the actual length is less then 8, I press enter, and nothing happens. I have to press it twice and still have this broken input and output.
The output goes to a new line, but it's not how it has to work.

There's my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX 8 // not including '\0' symbol

void printAsterisks(uint8_t);
void clearInputBuffer(void);

int main(void) {

    char word[MAX + 1], temp;
    int length, index;

    printAsterisks(46);
    printf("Please, type in any string. To exit give me #.\n");
    printAsterisks(46);

    while(1) {
        index = 0;
        printf("Your string : "); 

        fgets(word, MAX + 1, stdin);
            
        if(word[0] == '#') {
                printAsterisks(39);
                printf("The program has been cancelled by User.\n");
                printAsterisks(39);
                break;
        }

        clearInputBuffer();

        length = strlen(word);
            
        for(index = 0; index < length / 2; index++) {
                temp = word[index];
                word[index] = word[length - index - 1];
                word[length - index - 1] = temp;
        }

        printf("Reversed    : %s\n", word);
    }

    return 0;
}

void printAsterisks(uint8_t count) {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void clearInputBuffer(void) {
    static char buff;
    while((buff = getchar()) != '\n' && buff != EOF);
}
```

Comment: Please don't show images of text, copy-paste text *as text* into your question. That includes output from your programs.

Comment: Your `clearInputBuffer` function is invalid. The [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an **`int`** which is rather important for the comparison agains the `int` value `EOF`.

Comment: and `buff` doesn't need to be `static` in that function, `int buff` will do.

Comment: Don't forget that `fgets()` retains the newline (if there is one, and if there is room). So you need to [remove that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input/28462221#28462221) before reversing the string, or otherwise take account of it.

Comment: @WeatherVane I made it static to avoid unnecessary memory leaks. Cause it just creates a new variable every time I call this function and it also allocates new piece of memory what I don't want to happen.

Comment: @GeorgeGlebov the local variable is allocated on the stack and removed automatically at the end of the function. There is no memory leak.

Comment: You can still edit your question to remove the picture of text and add the plain text. You wouldn't even need to include all the unused space on the screen but only the relevant text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your attempt to flush the input buffer.

The `fgets` call reads and includes the newline in the buffer, *if it fits*.

When you enter less than `MAX` characters the `fgets` call will read the newline, but you still call `clearInputBuffer` which will attempt to read until the *next* newline.

You need to check if the buffer `word` includes the newline or not, and only call `clearInputBuffer` if there's no newline in it.

You can use the [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) function to check for the newline, as well as use its returned position to set the null-terminator to "remove" the newline from the buffer:

```
// strcspn will return the beginning index of the sub-string you search for
// Or the index of the null-terminator if the sub-string wasn't found
size_t newline_pos = strcspn(word, "\n");

if (word[newline_pos] == '\n')
{
    // There's a newline in the input, remove it
    word[newline_pos] = '\0';
}
else
{
    // There's no newline, skip the remainder of the line
    clearInputBuffer();
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU. There was really a huge gap in my logic. So, I've done what you said and now it works absolutely correctly. I understand now why trying to flush the input when my enter is less than MAX is absurd and absolutely nonsense. 
Thanks for this clear explanation dude.
I haven't learned <string.h> yet so I had no chance to come up with the idea of using strcspn().

Answer (score 1):

As @Some programmer dude said, the `clearInputBuffer` function was invalid, and I changed it a little bit. I assume you meant it to clear `word`. I also made `word` and `temp` global, and called `clearInputBuffer` after instead of before parsing the string and reversing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX 8 // not including '\0' symbol

char word[MAX + 1], temp;

void printAsterisks(uint8_t);
void clearInputBuffer(void);

int main(void) {
    int length, index;

    printAsterisks(46);
    printf("Please, type in any string. To exit give me #.\n");
    printAsterisks(46);

    while(1) {
        index = 0;
        

        fgets(word, MAX + 1, stdin);
        
        if(word[0] == '#') {
                printAsterisks(39);
                printf("The program has been cancelled by User.\n");
                printAsterisks(39);
                break;
        }
        
        length = strlen(word);
        
        for(index = 0; index < length / 2; index++) {
                temp = word[index];
                word[index] = word[length - index - 1];
                word[length - index - 1] = temp;
        }

        printf("Reversed    : %s\n", word);

        clearInputBuffer();
    }

    return 0;
}

void printAsterisks(uint8_t count) {
    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void clearInputBuffer() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i ++) {
        word[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work but you've helped me with clearing the string. Yeah, that was my whitespace.